# How to add the checked attribute to check box field which having some class using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want add the checked attribute for which element has some class called 'addCheck', here is my code :

```
  <input type="checkbox" id="due_date" name="due_date"  class='addCheck'>
```

Here is jquery code for trial:

```
   $(".addCheck" ).attr('checked','checked');
```

Comment: Your code should work. [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kce668c3/)

Comment: your code is working http://jsfiddle.net/carunchandran/mt7fjt6p/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this `.attr()`

```
$('.addCheck').attr('checked',true);
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/carunchandran/mt7fjt6p/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Use `.prop()` function:

```
$('.addCheck').prop('checked', true);
```

Answer (score 0):

`$('input.addCheck:checked')` should also return